# I want to deinstall News Republic from my HTC U Ultra, how can I do that?

Tags: malware, htc

I have one HTC U Ultra that has [News Republic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobilesrepublic.appy) installed.

I want to disable the push notifications or **deinstall** this program. How can I do that? On another HTC U Ultra the program is not installed so there has to be a way to get rid of it. I found *Notifications* and chose **Block all**. Hopefully this is enough to disable the push notifications.

But better: Can I **deinstall** this program?

Comment: Is that installed by your OEM or carrier? If yes, you would require root to uninstall or freeze it. You can still try opening the app from Play Store and uninstalling from there